# bash exec stderror stdout to normal php error_log

Tags: php, bash

Hi I'm running a PHP script via command line from a bash script. I am able to get the PHP errors appended to a single file with 2>> but I was wondering if I could send the errors to the standard PHP error_log file.

```
exec nohup php $PHP_SCRIPT_PATH 2>> $LOG_PATH & EPID=$!
```

Also when I do try to write to the php error_log file, I get write permission.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: PHP's usual error log is probably created under your webserver's userid, so either run it under that id, grant yourself permissions on the log file (make it 666), or add yourself to the log file's group and give the group write permissions (x6x)

Comment: Note in @Marc B's comment, `6` is actually read *and* write. There are good reasons to prevent reading from log files (all sorts of stuff gets thrown in there, passwords etc). For owner all, everyone else write only, use `0622`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get your permission problem managed this will not work, because you write from two processes to the same file. This will most likely produce garbage in the error_log.

You have to prevent PHP writing to the error_log. Instead you have to configure PHP to write to STDERR. And than you can redirect the output to a single file.